# Importing Data from file into DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I made a Windows Forms application in Visual Studio, and into initial form put one DataGridView (from toolbox). Then I made dataset and extract data from file into dataset. I tried to put data from dataset into GridView but when I started the form nothing happened. Grid was empty. What did I do wrong? Here is what I tried:

```
dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
dataGridView1.DataSource = MakeDataTable();
```

MakeDataTable() is method that returns DataSet (it's valid). dataGridView1 is object of class DataGridView that I got from toolbox. The grid just remained empty, nothing happened even though there was no error in compiling.
Then I tried to just make DataGridView on Form1 (default form), in similar way. I erased DataGrid View from form Design and added line:

```
DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
```

It didn't work either, I didn't know how to put that to be visible on form.

This worked but it opened another form so I had two forms, one empty and second one with gridView properly populated with data:

```
Form form1 = new Form();
DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
dataGridView1.DataSource = MakeDataTable();
form1.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
form1.ShowDialog();
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you try setting it to a BindingSource and then set DataSource as the BindingSource?

Answer (score 0):

If `MakeDataTable` returns a `DataSet`:

```
**// Add these lines of code to your source**
DataSet ds = MakeDataTable();
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
dataGridView1.DataMember = ds.Tables[0].TableName;
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true; 

form1.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
form1.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: What does the third line of code means? The one with "Tablename". Wouldn't this still open two forms instead of one? Sorry if I am asking stupid questions, I am new at this.

Comment: @user2806097 We all are here to teach and learn so there is nothing that can be said 'stupid'. When you create a DataSet you can put multiple DataTables inside, either having relation or not. This line tells the datagrid to pick the first DataTable in the generated DataSet. Form openning is completely different story. A form is usually openned by calling Show() or ShowDialog().

Comment: @user2806097 And one more thing: Did you try the code? Does it work? Did it solve your problem?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I didn't know that. Sorry but I didn't try the code. Problem is, if I use new form1 (Form form1  = new Form()), it will open two forms instead of one again. And if I use form object that's already given on design, there's no Controls.Add method to use.